# how can i improve my stamina?

Tags: workout-routines, stamina

I tried to "run" and i used the land-posts as a short goal but even that short distance gave me a hard time.
I really need an idea or advice of how i can properly improve my stamina (safely). Right now i'm lacking the experience and knowledge.
I want to have a healthier lifestyle!

Comment: Hey Ripeka, welcome to Fitness.SE. You'll notice this was closed as a duplicate. The search bar can be a bit tricky at times and I suggest you read the short help section: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: thank you so much! i really needed some help with that!